# linux bad interpreter permission denied cant load gnome

Tags: linux, bash

I was trying to set up a vnc remote access to my RaspPi, from my laptop.
I am using debian on my laptop. I couldn't configure this correctly so i went to sleep.

I had to made a file called sh that contained:

```
#!/bin/sh
vncserver :0 -geometry 1920x1080 -depth 24 -dpi 96
```

I don't really know what im doing, i don't know bash scripting i was just
following a manual.

When i turned on my laptop the next day, gnome did not load and i saw a lot of [FAILED] flags during the boot and got the command line. I thought no biggy and used startx, but i got this output:

```
-bash /usr/bin/startx: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

with sudo:
     sudo: unable to execute /usr/bin/startx: Permission denied

and with SU:

```
-bash /usr/bin/startx: /bin/sh: bad interpreter: Permission denied
```

my permissions on startx are
-rwxr-xr-x or 755

I do not know exactly what to do, if i have to add startx to the PATH variable or if it has to do with permissions. I have looked on line for other anwsers and can't find anything specific for this problem. I am a linux newbie who hasn't gotten into the OS that much and only uses the desktopversion to program and get a solid, smooth, boot and runtime.

I just want debian to boot like it did before.

I hope that my question is clear (i have gotten reported that i don't make good questions)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you've corrupted your interpreter AKA /bin/sh.
Try this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/135217/how-to-replace-fix-a-messed-up-bin-sh-and-bin-dash

Comment: Thank you, i learned something today. If its not too much to ask, do you think you could tell me why i got a -1 ? Was my problem just to trivial for stackoverflow?